# python: how do i always start from the second row in csv?

Tags: python, csv

b holds the contents of a csv file

i need to go through every row of b; however, since it has a header, i dont want to pay attention to the header. how do i start from the second row?

```
for row in b (starting from the second row!!):
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prepend a `next(b)` (in every recent version of Python; `b.next()` in older ones) to skip the first row (if `b` is an iterator; if it is, instead, a list, `for row in b[1:]:`, of course).

Answer (score 4):

```
b.next()
for row in b:
    # do something with row
```

But consider using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module, especially with DictReader.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use a [DictReader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). It will consume the first row for you

Comment: How do you skip lines using DictReader ?

Comment: @LymanZerga, not sure what you mean? DictReader is for a specific purpose where the first line contains the names of the columns, and all the following lines contain the data. Perhaps you mean to filter some lines before passing them to DictReader?

Comment: yes, thats correct. I have some lines before the table headers.How do I ignore them ? DictReader works fine when I remove them from the csv and converts the csv-table  to a dict

Comment: @LymanZerga, you should use the `Ask Question` button. We are not supposed to use comments for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='') as filecsv:
   datafile = csv.writer(filecsv)
   datafile.writerows(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got a new approach to do this by using **csv.reader**'s *line_num*:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open(myfile))
for line in reader:
    if reader.line_num == 1:
        continue
    print(line)
```

This code was tested under Python 3.6.8